# Object Array of length 0 but it still contains Info

Tags: java

Below I have pasted some code that I have been working on. I need to get a Target Line from the Mixer but I can't figure out how to request one with the Line.Info[] array. It has a length of 0 but if I output it as a string it holds a single line of information. I want to cast it but I don't know how to do it properly.

Thanks,
Hat

```
 package soundconnect;


    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
    import javax.sound.sampled.Line;
    import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
    import javax.sound.sampled.Mixer;

    public class SoundConnect {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException {

        Mixer.Info [] Mixes = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo(); 
        Mixer Sys_Mix = AudioSystem.getMixer(Mixes[1]);
        Line.Info[] T_NFO = Sys_Mix.getTargetLineInfo();

        Line Line1 = Sys_Mix.getLine(T_NFO[0]);      


        /* T_NFO has a length of 0 but has some information when I output it 
         * 
         */                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you output it as a string, you mean you're calling the `toString()` method of the `array`, which is an object in Java. This will print out the memory address and class name for the array. The default toString() printing for an array object has NOTHING to do with the elements in the array. It will print the same value regardless of what's stored inside of it, including if it has `0` length.

Comment: Makes sense. The output was definitely as you described. Thanks for your help...I would give you an upvote but I don't have any reputation yet. I will definitely check once it allows me.

Comment: @Adam No problem, if you're done with this question you can mark my answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark under my score. Or you can ask more questions here or by editting your post. Glad I could help.